# Calculate the limit given.

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you calculate

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x, y) \to (2, 2)} \dfrac{x^2 + 2y}{x^2 - 2y}$?

My attempt:

I approach the limit by using the line $x = 2$ (because the line passes through $(2, 2)$)
Now, I get
$\displaystyle \lim_{(x, y) \to (2, 2)} \dfrac{x^2 + 2y}{x^2 - 2y} = \lim_{(x, y) \to (2, 2)} \dfrac{2 + y}{2 - y}$

Now, what is next? If I approach by using the line $y = 2$ or by using the polar coordinates as well, it leads to the same cases. 
Regards!

Comment: The limit doesn't exist

Comment: $8/0$ is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, I see that now.  But the limit does fail to exist.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I like to have variables
go to zero.
So,
setting
$x = a+2, y = b+2$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x^2 + 2y}{x^2 - 2y}
&=\dfrac{(a+2)^2 + 2(b+2)}{(a+2)^2 - 2(b+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{a^2+4a+4+ 2b+4}{a^2+4a+4 - 2b-4}\\
&=\dfrac{a^2+4a+ 2b+8}{a^2+4a - 2b}\\
\end{array}
$

As $a, b \to 0$,
the numerator goes to $8$
and the denominator
goes to $0$,
so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Hi Marty.  Happy New Year.  The limit fails to exist, but not simply because the denominator approaches $0$.  Note that it can approach $0^+$ or $0^-$

Comment: Yes, it is also possible to go directly for $f(2,2+b)=-1-\frac 8{2b}$ which has a simpler form and shows the $\pm\infty$ divergence. (i.e. $a=0$). But anyway, the method is fine, so (+1).

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y) = \dfrac{x^2+2y}{x^2-2y}$.

Consider 2 sequences  z_n :=(x_n,y_n) 
converging  to (2,2).

1) Let $x_n= 2 +1/n$, $y_n= 2+2/n$.

$f(x_n,y_n) = $

$\dfrac{ 4+4/n +1/n^2 +4 +4/n}{4 +4/n +1/n^2 - 4 - 4/n}=$

$\dfrac{8 +8/n +1/n^2}{1/n^2} =$

$n^2(8+8/n +1/n^2) = $

$8n^2 +8n +1.$

$\lim_{n.\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n,y_n) = +\infty.$

2) Now let

$x_n = 2 - 1/n$; $y_n = 2 +2/n$ ;

$f(x_n,y_n) = $

$\dfrac{4 -4/n +1/n^2 + 4 +4/n}{4 -4/n +1/n^2 -4 - 4/n}=$

$\dfrac{8 +1/n^2}{ -8/n +1/n^2}=$

$-\dfrac{8n +1/n}{ 8 - 1/n}.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n,y_n)= -\infty.$

Hence the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that the limit doesn't exist because when you plug $(2,2)$ the numerator remains positive while the denominator tends to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The limit does not exists, indeed for $x=2+t$ and $y=2-t$ for $t\to0$

$$\dfrac{x^2 + 2y}{x^2 - 2y}=\dfrac{(2+t)^2 + 2(2-t)}{(2+t)^2 - 2(2-t)}=\dfrac{t^2+2t+8}{t^2+6t}=\dfrac{t+2+\frac8t}{t+6}\to\begin{cases}+\infty \quad t\to0^+\\-\infty \quad t\to0^- \end{cases}$$